# Selenium WebDriver: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json Version=4.0.2.0'

Tags: selenium, webdriver, json.net

Selenium's webdriver gives me that error when trying to use the Chrome or IE driver.
I have got Selenium via Nuget, so it should be giving me the correct libraries. However, it seems to want a reference to Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.2.0 rather than 4.0.3 which is the one currently inside the NuGet package.

How do I get round this issue?

**UPDATE**

I got this working, in part trying to fix another problem. See my other post:
[Selenium WebDriver - FirefoxDriver error: Failed to start up socket within 45000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661704/selenium-webdriver-firefoxdriver-error-failed-to-start-up-socket-within-45000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the Nuget package.  Selenium is relatively new to Nuget, and the team has been having problems building a package that can be used easily.  The primary .NET developer has said that the 2.8.x Nuget package will be better.  That's due out sometime this week.

Comment: ok great, I'll hang fire until that is released and check if it resolves the problem.

Comment: please see my update in the original question. Shall I close this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use x86 not ANY CPU, then will work. Your project is set to ANY CPU. Change it to x86.