# Where can I find a definitive Selenium WebDriver to Firefox Compatibility Matrix?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver, compatibility

I have worked on a number of projects using Selenium Java and the Firefox Web Driver, on a variety of platforms. Time and again, I come across incompatibilities between the version of the Selenium WebDriver we use and the version of Firefox installed.

The first line of defence is, of course, to make sure that we use the latest version of WebDriver and the latest version of FireFox.

Sometimes, that is not possible though, because we are using an older version of Java, or simply because the path of least resistance is to use the version of Firefox that is distributed with the OS.

I would really like to have a reliable Compatibility Matrix that tells me which version of Firefox I can use with which version of Selenium WebDriver. Where can I find one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364512/documentation-confusion-what-version-of-firefox-doesselenium-support . This question has a variety of links (in particular the release notes)  that likely provide the information that you are looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was looking for something similar just recently and found that the Changelog is probably the best place to look at for compatibility questions:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG

(used to be at http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG when Selenium was hosted on Google Code).

All the most recent version have a support up to Firefox v XX comment at the very top of each version.
The older ones you have to read in the comments a little, but they will say which version is the greatest supported for that release.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

There is a great support matrix at
https://github.com/santiycr/selenium-firefox-support-matrix

Comment: Useful, but appears to no longer be maintained