# Firefox Webdriver disabled when running test in selenium webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I am having a problem whereby running a test using selenium webdriver in firefox starts the firefox browser with firefox webdriver disabled as shown below.

[image: firefox webdriver disabled]

Because of this the test times out with the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary
FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows:
```

If I quickly enable the webdriver and restart the browser the test manages to run and complete itself so I'm guessing the problem is just that this add-on starts disabled when running a test.
How can I remedy this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Selenium and FireFox you're using. Incompatible versions can result in these kinds of problems. See: [Where can I find a definitive Selenium WebDriver to Firefox Compatibility Matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358859/where-can-i-find-a-definitive-selenium-webdriver-to-firefox-compatibility-matrix)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already checked the versioning should be compatible (I'm using selenium version 2.42.2 and firefox 29). It runs properly with the firefox webdriver extension enabled manually so I'm just wondering why it is disabled to begin with which prevents it from working

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only option at the moment is to use Marionette WebDriver

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

That works for Selenium 3 WebDriver tests. However if you use some framework on top of this you should check its roadmap to get information on when "geckodriver" or Marionette is going to be supported there.

Most likely the easiest approach to solve the issue in question for now is to downgrade browser (e.g. to Firefox 46) and use FireFox driver.

Answer (score -2):

Try remove the extension completely. Normally Seleniums FirefoxDriver is enough to start your test.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

This should work without any external Firefox Plugins.

Comment: I am using 'WebDriver driver = new Firefoxdriver()' to start the browser. Thing is, the extension only appears once I start running a webdriver test in the firefox browser that the test is running in. Thanks!

Comment: That is not an option with new FF versions where driver extension is disabled.