# Python Selenium Webdriver hangs

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I recently upgraded from
Firefox 16 to  29
Selenium 2.33 to 2.43

The previous set up is working fine but after upgradation I see it is hanging at the beginning step itself:

```
firefoxprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_directory = firefoxProfilePath)
firefoxprofile.set_preference('webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer', False)
firefoxprofile.set_preference('webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs', True)
firefoxprofile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
firefoxprofile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
downloadLocation = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'results', config.IDL_IP)                           
firefoxprofile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 0)
firefoxprofile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', downloadLocation)
firefoxprofile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', downloadFormat)
firefoxprofile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', downloadFormat)
firefoxprofile.update_preferences()

firefoxdriver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefoxprofile )
```

it hangs at the final step
I'm also running this on a headless server using `Xvfb`.

Comment: Could you also show how do you start `Xvfb`?

Comment: I dont start Xvfb, it is installed. I use pyvirtualdisplay to run selenium in headless mode. One more point is that if I run one script at a time it works but if I try to run concurrently then it hangs sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Most probably a firefox/selenium compatibility issue. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358859/where-can-i-find-a-definitive-selenium-webdriver-to-firefox-compatibility-matrix) helps.

(I would have rather added a comment but I am 4 rep points short of doing so).

Comment: I verified Selenium site and Selenium 2.43 supports Firefox 29 native elements

Comment: Reading this [changelog](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG) I found this: v2.43.0 - support Firefox 24, 31 and 32. Try one of these versions.