# watir with ruby on ubuntu not connecting

Tags: ruby, firefox, rspec, watir, watir-webdriver

I get the following error:

```
unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
```

I am trying to run Rspec with watir, the ruby gem, on an Ubuntu box.

But I keep getting this error on Firefox 42.

I'm not sure what I need to do to resolve this networking issue.

Read the following but I am on a way later version of Firefox:

[unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263564/unable-to-obtain-stable-firefox-connection-in-60-seconds-127-0-0-17055)

[Unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303161/unable-to-obtain-stable-firefox-connection-in-60-seconds-127-0-0-17055)

gem update selenium-webdriver

Comment: Verify you are using selenium-webdriver version 2.48.1. Firefox 42 does work on Ubuntu with that version of the gem.

Comment: thanks, I did a bundle update so it should be, but I can go and check....

Comment: * selenium-webdriver (2.48.1) --- so I think the issue must be something else.

Comment: Are you trying to run headless? Are you running Local or remote? Starting Firefox manually works?

Answer (score 0):

> Read the following but I am on a way later version of Firefox:

At the first link it says:

> [Update - this can (was for me) still be a fix for this issue in 2015
>   |mdurrant|]

And:

> Important note: The selenium-webdriver gem is updated, and a new
>   version released, for every subsequent version of Firefox. Presently,
>   version 2.25.0 is needed to support Firefox 15.

But your solutions was:

```
gem update selenium-webdriver
```

...which is not my interpretation of those posts.  My interpretation is NOT that you always need the latest selenium for whatever version of Firefox you are using--rather they are trying to tell you that you need to match a selenium version to a Firefox version.

And in fact, there is an SO question titled:

> Where can I find a definitive Selenium WebDriver to Firefox
>   Compatibility [Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358859/where-can-i-find-a-definitive-selenium-webdriver-to-firefox-compatibility-matrix)?

So, it looks to me like the latest version of selenium does not support Firefox 42.  You need to install an earlier version of Firefox.

Comment: Each version of Selenium explicitly supports the current and previous Releases of Firefox, and the current and previous Extended Support Releases of Firefox. Sometimes when new Firefox releases happen, Mozilla changes something that needs to be adjusted in the Selenium code, which requires users to either downgrade Firefox or wait for the next release of Selenium. In this case, Firefox 42 works just fine with selenium-webdriver 2.48.1 so there is no need to downgrade.

Comment: Hm maybe there's an issue with network access since it says something about the IP address?