# Which firefox version and gecko driver version is compatible with selenium-java-3.5.3

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Could you please tell me Which firefox version and gecko driver version is compatible with selenium-java-3.5.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find a definitive Selenium WebDriver to Firefox Compatibility Matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358859/where-can-i-find-a-definitive-selenium-webdriver-to-firefox-compatibility-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a help from the below URLs:

https://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp 
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG