# Selenium FireFox Driver Exception

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, driver

I had a number of Selenium tests written using the Firefox driver which worked fine. But for some reason now I am getting an exception when trying to instantiate the Firefox driver. Does anybody know of any updates Firefox have made that might have affected this?

Here are the two lines of code. The exception occurs on the 2nd line:-

```
private IWebDriver _webDriver;
_webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Below is the exception I ham getting:-

> "An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Comment: What version of Selenium + Firefox are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error recently. Are you using the port for some other application as well?

The topic was already discussed right here:
[Selenium WebDriver - FirefoxDriver error: Failed to start up socket within 45000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661704/selenium-webdriver-firefoxdriver-error-failed-to-start-up-socket-within-45000)
; the solution was not the port, but some other possibility. Might want to check it out.

Greetz, me.