# Selenium Firefox WebDriver in WCF throwing "failed to start up socket within 45000 ms"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Exception stack trace:

*OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverServer.ConnectToBrowser(TimeSpan timeToWait)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverServer.Start()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary'2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at DtvAutomation.Selenium.Api.SeleniumFirefoxTest.CreateWebDriver()
   at DtvAutomation.Selenium.Api.SeleniumTest'1.Run()*

The code that throws the exception is calling the Firefox WebDriver constructor:

```
protected override FirefoxDriver CreateWebDriver()
{
    lock(this.syncRoot)
    {
        var ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
        var ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        return new FirefoxDriver(
            binary: ffBinary,
            profile: ffProfile,
            commandTimeout: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
    }
}
```

I am using selenium 2.46 (via NuGet package) from a Visual Studio 2013 - "WCF Application Service" project. Firefox is 38.0.5 (latest). 
When I start the WCF from Visual Studio (debug mode) everything works fine - no exceptions. When I publish the WCF to local IIS it throws this error.

I tried the following things:

- Updated NuGet packages - make sure I'm up-to-date
- Downgraded Firefox to version 34.0.5
- Upgraded Firefox to latest version
- Opened port 7055 from firewall
- Change credentials for IIS application / app-pool, used the Administrator account
- On exception, re-try to initialize WebDriver using another port

None of these seem to work.
Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: you can edit question. And add relevant things there, most of users don't read comments. And comments may also be get deleted at later point of time.

Comment: A very likely duplicate with heaps of solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39362003/495455

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Changing the app pool identity to something like LocalSystem solved the issue, but you don't want to do that in production.

Instead I found a setting, `LoadUserProfile`, on the Application Pool's Advanced Settings,  that was set to `False`. If you set it to `True`, the application pool loads a user profile which in turn gets rid of the Selenium issue.

You need to run at least IIS 7, and you can read more about the setting [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2009/03/08/iis-7-tip-3-you-can-now-load-the-user-profile-of-the-application-pool-identity/).

Comment: @Elmue the OP asked a question about Firefox WebDriver run through WCF/IIS. If you have something constructive to add, please do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution was to switch app pool identity from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to more powerful user.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced a similar issue. I was using 
Selenium Webdriver Nuget Package v2.48
Firefox version 41.0

Initially, thinking that it was an issue with a version conflict between FF and Webdriver, I upgraded Webdriver to this version. Nothing fixed.
Next, I downgraded FF to v 31.0. Nothing fixed.
Third, I thought about what was a recent change, and it was this line of code for me

```
p.SetPreference("webdriver.log.file", "/tmp/firefox_console");
```

Within this block of code

```
            FirefoxProfile p = new FirefoxProfile();
            //p.SetPreference("webdriver.log.file", "/tmp/firefox_console");
            //p.SetPreference("dom.ipc.plugins.flash.disable-protected-mode", true);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(p);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

After commenting out the SetPreference method = **Success! Firefox was opening as expected.**

Answer (score -1):

I think problem state with timeout of firefox webdriver. You can do with following which include Firefox profile and TimeSpan which may reduced timeout of Firefox web driver.

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), 
                                      new FirefoxProfile(), 
                                      TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

Comment: This answer is Nonsense