# Again timeout creating new FirefoxDriver with Firefox 43 and above

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-webdriver

With latest Selenium WebDriver v 2.50.00 I am getting (again) following exception:

> Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms. Attempted to connect to the
>   following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055

executing:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), firefoxProfile, pageLoadTimeout);
```

This happens **with version 43 and higher of Firefox**. I have downgraded Firefox to v. 39 and there it works OK.

It seems that this issue happened before couple of times with various versions of Selenium and Firefox, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8525) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31020721).

Any workaround for this or downgrading Firefox and waiting for a new version of Selenium WebDriver is the only way?

Comment: As a precision for other people who will encounter this problem, firefox 42 and lower works (I downgraded to 42).

Comment: With version 48.0.2 the same problem again........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It is bug which still going to resolve for latest versions
You need set the Preferences as `xpinstall.signatures.required", false`.

Below code is working for me but it is in java. you get the idea where you need to change

```
    WebDriver driver = null;
    final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Yes, great, adding a line `firefoxProfile.SetPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);` did the trick indeed.

Comment: `Firefox 48: (Pushed from Firefox 46). Release and Beta versions of Firefox for Desktop will not allow unsigned extensions to be installed, with no override. ` - what now?