# Timeout creating new FirefoxDriver with Firefox 48 and above

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I used to have a problem with Firefox 43 and above, which is described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35055498/2224701).

> Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms. Attempted to connect to the
> following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055

on line:

```
 driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), firefoxProfile, pageLoadTimeout);
```

The workaround was to add:

```
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
```

But now on 48.0.2 the problem is present again. I have found [this statement:](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing)

> Firefox 40-42: Firefox warns about signatures but doesn't enforce
> them.
>
> Firefox 43: Firefox enforces the use of signatures by default,
> but has a preference that allows signature enforcement to be disabled
> (xpinstall.signatures.required in about:config).
>
> Firefox 48: (Pushed from Firefox 46). Release and Beta versions of
> Firefox for Desktop will not allow unsigned extensions to be
> installed, **with no override**. Firefox for Android will enforce add-on
> signing, and will retain a preference — which will be removed in a
> future release — to allow the user to disable signing enforcement.

What now, how could this be fixed to load new FirefoxDriver? For Selenium.WebDriver I use NuGet package 2.53.1.

Comment: Is this just a bug report? Then it should be posted in the issue tracker for the FireFoxDriver.

Comment: @Stuartd No helpful answer there, only Steven was near. I need a c# answer compatible with 48 version.

Comment: No workaround there, other than using older Firefox: only signed extensions are now allowed, but it costs nothing to sign them, is not taking a lot of time, and it's an automatable process. So I suggest you bite the bullet and just sign your extension (if you are talking about custom extension). If youa re talking about Selenium web driver for firefox, then look up a gazillion questions about Selenium support on Firefox 48+

Comment: @KirilS. `gazillion questions about Selenium support on Firefox 48+` - no such found on SO.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=selenium+2.53+Firefox+48&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=kZPJV56mE9TEjAP_2YjYCg
Bottom line is: to test Firefox 48 you are expected to switch to Marionette driver

Comment: Do not see anywhere any guide, how to switch using c# and **working** version of Marionette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly frustrated with FF48's ban on the xpinstall.signatures.required override, I ended up switching over to Ice Dragon (Comodo's FF variant), which has *not* disabled xpinstall.signatures.required.

To force Selenium to use Comodo with Firefox 48 installed in parallel provide path to Comodo in `FireFoxBinary` constructor:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(
         new FirefoxBinary(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Comodo\IceDragon\IceDragon.exe"), 
         firefoxProfile);
```

Comment: Good option for now, I have added a code snippet, but perhaps the reason is just that Comodo is behind firefox in terms of features?