# Selenium WebDriver with Firefox error

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I have the problem: Win 8.1 (fresh, just installed), Firefox 34 (downgraded, tested also on 38 and 39), Selenium 2.46.0...
I receive:

> An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException'
>   occurred in WebDriver.dll
>
> Additional information: Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms.
>   Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055

Any idea how to make it to run?

On virtual server with Win7 - the same project is working well...

Comment: Please check if helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661704/selenium-webdriver-firefoxdriver-error-failed-to-start-up-socket-within-45000

Comment: You should report that to the Firefox Webdriver developers.

Comment: It makes sense that downgrading to version 31.6.0 ESR would solve the issue since that was the last version of Firefox that officially supported native events in Selenium 2.x .

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to download the latest References from "http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/";
2. Add reference with latest net40 dll's;
3. Build and run.