# Selecting all the values from the Listbox using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, listbox

I want to select all the values from the listbox.

I tried the below code, But unfortunately it is not selecting the last value in the listbox.

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:1479/WebPage.aspx");
            IWebElement dropdownElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ListBox1"));
            List<IWebElement> elements = dropdownElement.FindElements(By.TagName("option")).ToList();
            int totalElementCount = elements.Count - 1;
            Actions act = new Actions(driver);
            act.ClickAndHold(elements[0]).Perform();
            act.MoveToElement(elements[totalElementCount]).Release().Perform();
```

ListBox Control:-

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item4</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item5</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item6</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
```

Output:-

[image]

I'm not sure why it is not selecting the last value from the Listbox. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [SelectElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm). It is the easiest way to work with select. See code below:

```
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(d.FindElement(By.Id("ListBox1")));
for (int i=0; i<select.Options.Count;i++)
{
    select.SelectByIndex(i);
}
```

Comment: I want to select all the elements. Ur code will not maintain the state for the dropdown values..i mean it will select only the value 'Item6' at last, not all the values

Comment: @Geetha Did you try it yet?

Comment: My bad..I didn't set the property to multiple in the listbox..your code works fine

Comment: @Geetha No problem. I'm going to tell you about the multiple property but you've already found it. ^.^

Comment: Yesterday i tried this logic, at that time i haven't enabled the multiple property

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have this in your code

```
    int totalElementCount = elements.Count - 1;
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.ClickAndHold(elements[0]).Perform();
    act.MoveToElement(elements[totalElementCount]).Release().Perform();
```

Notice that you have selected all elements except 1?

```
    int totalElementCount = elements.Count - 1;
```

If you change that to

```
    int totalElementCount = elements.Count;
```

Does it work then?
Unfortunately I don't have the ability to execute your code on my machine(S) but it seems appropriate.

what happens if you say this instead

```
    act.ClickAndHold(elements[elements.Count]).Perform();
    or
    act.ClickAndHold(elements[elements.Count - 1]).Perform();
```

or possibly this will help

```
        for(int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++) 
        {
               act.ClickAndHold(elements[i]).Perform();
        }
```

I tried to get run your code.. but unfortunately ran into too many issues
with Selenium and firefox...
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/8188839/1869220

Can't afford to change my environment for this. Sorry :(

Comment: @Martin - I tried that one as well, It is throwing Index out of bound exception. Becasue the values are identified by its index

Comment: What about the line
        act.ClickAndHold(elements[0]).Perform();
Is that where you select the first element?

Comment: It will select the first element and hold it

Comment: what happens if you say this instead

        act.ClickAndHold(elements[elements.Count]).Perform();
        or
       act.ClickAndHold(elements[elements.Count - 1]).Perform();

or possibly this will help


            for(int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++) 
            {
                   act.ClickAndHold(elements[i]).Perform();
            }

Comment: act.ClickAndHold(elements[elements.Count - 1]).Perform(); - nothing is selected in the listbox

Comment: act.ClickAndHold(elements[elements.Count]).Perform(); - Index out of bound exception thrown

Comment: check revised answer... the loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109589/discussion-between-ca-martin-and-geetha).

Comment: @martin - Buaban's answer works fine for me...thanks for your time

Comment: @Aishu - no problem glad you got it fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

By default click actions happen in the top left corner of the element.  You may want to try the middle on the last element.

```
    Integer iBottom = elements[totalElementCount].getSize().height;
    Integer iRight = elements[totalElementCount].getSize().width;
    actions.moveToElement(elements[totalElementCount], iRight/2, iBottom/2).release.perform();
```