# Which Firefox version is compatible with Selenium 2.53.0?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

Which Firefox version is compatible with Selenium 2.53.0? I tried Firefox 45.0 and I am getting this exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary           
FirefoxBinary(/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin) on   port 7055; process output follows: 
foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"l   ocales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"45.0","maxVersion":"45.*"},{"id":"xpcshell@tests.mozilla.org","minVersion":"0","maxVersion":"10"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"seen":true}
```

Comment: I was using old version of selenium-firefox-driver in POM.xml, after changing it to 2.53.0, issue is fixed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had the similar problem running Selenium Webdriver 2.53.0 with Firefox 47.0.

**Selenium Webdriver 2.53.0** works with **Firefox 46.0**. You can find the the mentioned version at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox.

Comment: And here's the direct link to download Firefox 46.0 - [32-bit (en-us)](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%2046.0.exe) and [64-bit (en-us)](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0/win64/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%2046.0.exe)

Comment: Is there any page which says which version of driver is compatible with which version of firefox? This gets frustrating at times.

Comment: It would be nice if people would put the OS versions on these posts if possible. jacobcs is correct that the documentation on this stuff is AWFUL. Good luck getting Selenium/Ubuntu/FF working with the latest versions. Question? Do the people who work on Selenium even know how to turn it on? Is is a secret?

Answer (score 0):

Also you could try to add:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
WebDriver driver=new  FirefoxDriver();
```

if it is also not working, then you need to downgrade your FF

Answer (score -1):

hi I had the same problem, I hope you have solved yours, but maybe my answer can help someone else.

i found firefox 26, selenium 2.48.2 and a webdriver that work very good together. here are the download links:

[phpSeleniumWebDrive](http://www.mediafire.com/file/nhb8ab9bz2xlhu4/php-Selenium2.48.2-firefox_26.0.zip/file)

[selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2](http://www.mediafire.com/file/vq6c6rjtjrvhbgl/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar/file)

[firefox26](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/26.0/win32/ast/)

Comment: Provided links are not from the original sources. These could contain harmful content.