# Selenium Ruby - Can't run the start example (linux)

Tags: ruby, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want use Selenium with Ruby. I'm on a Ubuntu 15.10

First, I've installed the selenium-webdriver gem.

Now I'm trying to execute the example code:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.send_keys "Hello WebDriver!"
element.submit

puts driver.title

driver.quit
```

When I do so I get this error:

```
/home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock': end of file reached (EOFError)
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1414:in `block in transport_request'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `catch'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `transport_request'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1384:in `request'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1377:in `block in request'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `response_for'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:58:in `request'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:134:in `get'
from /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:33:in `to'
```

When executed, a Firefox window is opened and closed instantaneously (before the `driver.quit`).

Comment: Running Ubuntu 14.04 here, but I had to downgrade my Firefox version from  47 to 46 to get selenium to work. See [which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-2-53-0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747430/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-2-53-0). There's a recent issue thread on the [selenium github page](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2110) about it.