# What is the best way to check if the browser to use in Selenium WebDriver is compatible?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using c# selenium webdriver version 2.53. Similar to this post: 
[Which Firefox version is compatible with Selenium 2.53.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747430/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-2-53-0)

I am getting the generic Webdriverexception for incompatible Firefox versions. Is there a good/correct way to handle all incompatible browsers so I could display an error message stating that the browser being used is incompatible?

Comment: Is the wrong version exception not enough? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What I want is to be able to handle all incompatible browsers correctly. Using selenium 2.53.1 with firefox 47.0 would result in another Webdriverexception with a different message:
"Failed to start up socket within 45000 milliseconds. Attempted to connect to the following address: __"
while using it on an older version of chrome results in InvalidOperationException:
"unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 51.0.2704"
Given all these different exceptions and messages, is there a general way/method out to filter out browser incompatiblity exceptions?

Comment: Is webdriverexception thrown only when Firefox version is incompatible? And could there be other exceptions thrown for different versions?