# Using Firefox profile not working with other device, in C# Selenium

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have done this to use the user's default Firefox profile:

```
var profileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();
FirefoxProfile profile = profileManager.GetProfile("default");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

And this:

```
string pathToCurrentUserProfiles = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%APPDATA%") + @"\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles";
string[] pathsToProfiles = Directory.GetDirectories(pathToCurrentUserProfiles, "*.default", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(pathsToProfiles[0]);
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

And this:

```
var firefoxService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.Profile = profile;
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxService, options, new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0));
```

They are all working to use my Firefox profile in my working device, but when the released application is being used on the other device, the application looks waiting for a timeout, then open the geckodriver and the thread will now be done.

What is the problem here? It's working well in my device...

Comment: Could the downgrade of Firefox to its v47 or by disabling its extensions will allow the other device to make it work?

Comment: I saw your altruistic Bounty but cant tag you in the comments there, are you using Firefox Sync'ing? [How to sync your add-ons with another copy of Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/sync-your-add-ons-another-copy-firefox)

Comment: @JeremyThompson Nope, I'm not using Firefox Syncing.. Maybe the 48 and the later versions of Firefox have restricted a browser driver.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/39362003/495455